# Heroku unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, heroku

I added the following heroku-buildpack:
google-chrome an heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
Then I set the environment variables

```
GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN = /app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome
GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM = /app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

And I get the folowing message:

```
Exception Type: WebDriverException
Exception Value:
Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 3.13.0-133-generic x86_64)
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response, line 194
```

I am struggle with it and dont know what  am I doing wrong?
And how do I know if I set the path of the variable correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Now its working greate, doe's are the steps I done
I set the enviroment varible as folow (you can do it form the heroku dashbord -> setting)

```
GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN =/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM= /app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

then in my djanogo project where I want to run selenuim

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

chrome_bin = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', None)
opts = ChromeOptions()
opts.binary_location = chrome_bin
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver", 
chrome_options=opts)# webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)
driver.get(url)
....
```

I got the help thanks to frbry from https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/issues/26#issuecomment-346647415

Comment: Is the language you're using is for python? Do you know how to fix it with javascript/Node?